# Bootstrap Collapse Showing Child Elements When Collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have a collapsible panel that contains multiple controls - text boxes, labels, drop downs etc, but whenever I use the following code, the collapse animation shows, but the items are still visible.

This is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Collapsible List Group</h2>
  <p>Click on the collapsible panel to open and close it.</p>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          Collapsible list group
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="collapse1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            <span>
              <label for="#txtbox">Text Here</label>
              <input id="txtbox" type="text"/>
            </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Some screenshots to show what I'm talking about:

Not Collapsed:

[image]

Collapsed:

[image]

Comment: Why did you tag your question with Bootstrap 4 when your example uses 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the "show" class from the field you wish to collapse:
Edit: Include the class "in" when wanting to show uncollapsed by default.

```
<div class="container">
      <h2>Collapsible List Group</h2>
      <p>Click on the collapsible panel to open and close it.</p>
      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              Collapsible list group
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse in" id="collapse1">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                <span>
                  <label for="#txtbox">Text Here</label>
                  <input id="txtbox" type="text"/>
                </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```